# How to correctly release memory from JNI?

Tags: java, c++, memory, java-native-interface

From Java I call a matrix multiplication (used for calculating the power of a square matrix):

```
// Java
public class Matrix {
    // ...
    native void power(double[] a, double[] b, int rows, int cols, int exponent);
    // ...
}
```

In C++ this is implemented the following way:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL power(JNIEnv* env, jobject o,
    jdoubleArray vals, jdoubleArray originalMatrix, jint aRows, jint aCols, jint i) {
            
    jboolean isCopy;

    // Get input array and result array to write values to.
    jdouble* pa = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(vals, &isCopy);
    jdouble* po = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(originalMatrix, &isCopy);

    // Keeping the result of the k-th multiplication.
    jdouble* tmp = new double[aRows * aCols];

    for (int k = 1; k < i; k++) {
        multiply(po, pa, tmp, aRows, aCols, aCols);  // implemented elsewhere (but should be ok)
        memcpy(tmp, pa, aCols * aRows);
    }    
    
    env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(vals, pa, 0);    // <- THIS OK?
    env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(originalMatrix, po, 0);

    delete[] tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems about right. For the input array you could replace `0` with `JNI_ABORT` in the `ReleaseDoubleArrayElements` call to ensure that no write-back will be done in case `GetDoubleArrayElements` gave you a copy.

For the output array you could also consider using the input array's `isCopy` result to determine whether to use `SetDoubleArrayRegion` instead of `GetDoubleArrayElements`/`ReleaseDoubleArrayElements`.

Comment: What does JNI_ABORT mean actually'

Comment: It's described in [the JNI documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html).

Comment: which I read (Sorry, I should have asked better): "What does it mean `JNI_ABORT: free the buffer without copying back the possible changes` Which buffer? And, if I want the values calculated in C++ then I guess I want to have them in Java again, so would `JNI_ABORT` not be the wrong option for me?

Comment: _"Which buffer?"_  The one you got from `GetDoubleArrayElements`. _"if I want the values calcualted in C++ then I guess I want to have them in Java again"_ I was under the impression that one of the two arrays was only used as input. For such an array it would be appropriate to use `JNI_ABORT`.